# Increment a number by clicking onto a button

Tags: jquery

I have the number `$likes_number` in a div block on my page. I would like to know how to increment it dynamically by clicking on a button?

**My code:**

```
<div id="likes">
    <span class="figure">
        <?php echo $likes_number ;?>
    </span>
</div>
<button type="button" id="like" >Like</button>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<div id="likes">
    <span class="figure"></span>
</div>
<button type="button" id="like">Like</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clicks = 0; $("#like").click(function(){ clicks++; $('.figure').html(clicks);});
</script>
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/nTmu7/2/

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#like').click(function() {
    $('#likes span').text( parseInt($('#likes span').text()) + 1 );
});
```

You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/nayish/GCvnH/