# Trying to automate jQuery click event and displaying content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Could anyone tell me if it's possible to automate the following process. Basically, in my simple code below, I am using the jQuery `click()` event. So when a user clicks on the text `Click Me First Time!` and new text is shown below `Click Me Second Time!`. When a user clicks on `Click Me Second Time!`, a new text is shown below `Click Me Third Time!`.

I want to continue this process as long as user keep on clicking the latest text shown on the screen so far. By continue this process, I mean, when a user clicks on the latest text( here `Click Me Third Time!`, I want to display another text below and when user clicks that text again, I want to display another new text and so on and so forth)

Is there a way where I could automate this process instead of writing the `click()` event again and again because I am not sure how many times a user would keep on clicking the latest text. Please find my code below:

```js
$("#firstgrid").click(function() {
 //alert ("Text Clicked");
 
 $("<div />") 
              .append($("<div />", {
                  id: "secondgrid",
                 style: "margin:100px 10px 20px 100px "
              }))
               .appendTo(document.body);
              
              $("#secondgrid").text("Click Me Second Time!");
              
              
              $("#secondgrid").click(function() {
              
                  $("<div />") 
                  .append($("<div />", {
                      id: "thirdgrid",
                     style: "margin:100px 10px 20px 100px "
                  }))
                   .appendTo(document.body);
               
               
                   $("#thirdgrid").text("Click Me Third Time!");

                   });// End of onclick event
 
        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="firstgrid">Click Me First Time !</div>
```

Comment: So you want this to happen infinitely as many times as the user clicks?

Comment: Yes. That's true.

Comment: There is no ordinal utility by default, this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998005/ordinals-in-words-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increment a number by clicking onto a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183226/increment-a-number-by-clicking-onto-a-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by creating a handler function that is called on every `div.clickable`('clickable' is a class given to the elements that should be involved into the click process).

A brief explanation of the procedure, first we'll wrap all the `div`s in a wrapper `div`(we'll give it a class-name of 'wrapper' for example), we'll also give a class to all the elements that should be involved(I'll give them 'clickable' class in my snippet below), when a `div.clickable` is clicked we'll create a new `div` element give it the same class as the other `div`s(in my snippet the class is 'clickable'), then we'll add a click event listener to the newly created `div`, append it to the `DOM`, and finally we'll remove the click Event listener from the current clicked `div`.

Here's a demo snippet toto clarify all what being said

```js
// is used to count the 'divs'
var counter = 1;
// add click event listener to the div that's initially present in the page, Btw changing its class won't affect the script, but the newly created 'divs' should have the same class.
$('.clickable').on('click', handleClick);
// handler function to be called on each `div.clickable` click.
function handleClick(e) {
  var newEl = $("<div />", {
    class: "clickable",
    style: "margin:100px 10px 20px 100px ",
    text: 'click me for the ' + ++counter + ' time!'
  });
  // add click Event listener to the newly created div, the same function(here I name irt 'handleClick') is the handler.
  newEl.on('click', handleClick);
  $(this).parent().append(newEl);
  // remove click Event from the current clicked div.
  $(this).off('click');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="clickable">Click Me First Time !</div>
</div>
```

Hope I pushed you further.

Comment: Thanks very much. Appreciated !

Comment: Hey @ths , I used your approach in my code here(http://jsfiddle.net/pvs0ohuk/) but 1) instead of displaying text, I want to display the grid that I see only after clicking the text. Could you please tell me how can I include `$(".clickable").jqxGrid({.....` in place of `text` for the variable `newEl`? Or is it even possible to achieve it?

Comment: 2) Suppose if I want to destroy all the text/grid if a user clicks on any other row of the grid and start from the newly clicked row, then using this `$(".clickable").remove();` inside `handleClick` event destroys the whole table as soon as I click on it because we are using same class. Could you tell me if it's possible to achieve this thing? Thanks P.s: In case it helps  I can get the index value of the row that user clicks as far as the jQXgrid is concerned by putting this inside handleClick function : console.log(e.args.rowindex);

Comment: that'd be another question and another approach.

Answer (score -1):

[Increment a number by clicking onto a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183226/increment-a-number-by-clicking-onto-a-button)

Look here. You need to create a counter and then increment it and then you can append text to your html with a number in it.